# How to calculate $3*5*17*257-3^{16}$ using factorization formulas?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

look at this:

$2*4*10*82*6562-3^{16}$

It's easy to calculate it with elementary arithmetic.

but how to calculate it using factorization formulas?

Comment: Which one is your question?

Comment: Perhaps you should present the minuend as a product of prime divisors and then divide both sides by $3^n$, where $n$ is max. degree of $3$ in the minuend.

Comment: @BlueSky I added a remark in my answer on the telescopic essence of the matter - which makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2\times 4\times 10\times 82\times 6562-3^{16} $$ $$=(3^1-1)(3^1+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)-3^{16}$$ $$=(3^2-1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)-3^{16}$$ $$=(3^4-1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)-3^{16}$$ $$=(3^8-1)(3^8+1)-3^{16}$$ $$=(3^{16}-1)-3^{16}$$ $$=-1$$

Comment: Note that this can be viewed as collapsing a *telescoping* product - see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ It is a radix $\,3\,$ analog of this radix $\,10\,$ (decimal) computation

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad  \underbrace{9\cdot 11}\cdot 101\cdot 10001 - 10^8 $
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \underbrace{99 \cdot 101}$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \  \underbrace{9999\cdot 10001}$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \ 99999999 - 10^8\, =\, -1$

**Remark** $\ $ At the heart of the matter is the following *telescoping* product  (in your case $\,x=3).\,$ Notice that the same-colored terms all (diagonally) cancel out of the product.

$\qquad\qquad\, \displaystyle (x-1)(x+1)(x^2\!+1)(x^4\!+1)\quad\ \ \cdots\quad\ \ \ (x^{2^{\rm N}}\!+1)$

$\qquad\ \ \ = \ \displaystyle  \frac{\color{#0a0}{x-1}}{\color{#90f}1} \frac{\color{brown}{x^2-1}}{\color{#0a0}{x-1}}\frac{\color{royalblue}{x^4-1}}{\color{brown}{x^2-1}}\frac{\phantom{f(3)}}{\color{royalblue}{x^4-1}}\, \cdots\,  \frac{\color{#c00}{x^{2^{\rm N}}\!-1}}{\phantom{f(b)}}\frac{x^{2^{\rm N+1}}\!-1}{\color{#c00}{x^{\rm 2^N}\!-1}} \,=\,  \frac{x^{2^{\rm N+1}}-1}{\color{#90f}1} $

For further telescopic intuition see my many [posts on multiplicative telescopy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+multiplicative+telescopy)

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $$3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 = (2-1)(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1) = (2^2-1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1) = \dots$$

$$2 \cdot 4 \cdot 10 \cdot 82 \cdot 6562 = (3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)=\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the answer is quite a big number. So I don't think the exact value matters. I think you are asking how can you "compactify" your answer. I am assuming that your heading is your question. Write it as $(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1)-3^{16}$. Multiply the big 4 terms in brackets by $(2-1)$(its nothing but $1$). This starts your process of chain reaction. Multiply it by first term in bracket and you get $(2+1)(2-1)=2^2-1$, which in turn multiplies by the next term, then the next.... At last you get $2^16-1$. And therefore your answer is $$2^{16}-3^{16}-1$$.

Comment: My guess is that the title question should have had $-2^{16}$ rather than $-3^{16}$

Comment: @henry the question is right.